# Variadic constructor with enable_if and is_constructible

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, variadic-templates, type-traits

I have one class called `NameAndTag`. It has constructors:

```
    NameAndTag();
    NameAndTag(std::string name_or_tag);
    NameAndTag(boost::uuids::uuid tag) : Tag(tag) {}
```

Now, I want to define another class whose (template) constructor takes a variable number of "things" that can be passed to `NameAndTag::NameAndTag`. Also, I'd like the template types to be implicit.

I have tried different approaches. One that I was hopping to work was this one:

```
    template<typename... NameOrTag>
    PathToObject(std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_constructible_v<NameAndTag, NameOrTag>
    , NameOrTag&&>... obj_path);
```

However, I think the compiler has trouble figuring out what are the types for `NameOrTag`. The compiler says I am passing too many arguments, when the template accepts none. Here is a demo:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/10Lwxpt6niHUlaxv

To make the type of `NameOrTag` easier to figure out, I have tried:

```
    template<typename... NameOrTag>
    PathToObject(NameOrTag&&... obj_path,
        std::enable_if_t<
            std::conjunction_v
            <
                std::is_constructible_v<NameAndTag, NameOrTag>...
            >
            , bool> dummy = true);
```

But I suppose that mixing up pack templates and an optional argument is not supposed to work. The compiler says there is no match for `PathToObject("name", uuid)`. Here is a demo:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/sVviVKQ6uixYvKJ7

Does what I am trying to do make any sense?
How can I accomplish that? I am bound to C++17...

---

Problem solved! Thank you all! A few comments about my experience, ahead...

Solution given by the accepted answer:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/Me3XHlrtZ58ye7Hl

Here is my code:
https://github.com/andre-caldas/FreeCAD/blob/0af3ad0d8a9681a1b3931166791b8a93094f4746/src/Base/Accessor/ReferenceToObject.h#L46

Just FYI, since I like trouble, I have divided the template file into ".h" and ".inl" (for inline). Then, because of that, I was getting some sort of "redefinition of default template argument"... because you cannot use the `= nullptr` when you write the definition of the template. See:
https://github.com/andre-caldas/FreeCAD/blob/0af3ad0d8a9681a1b3931166791b8a93094f4746/src/Base/Accessor/ReferenceToObject.inl#L39

---

Edit: I am bound to C++17.

Edit 2: Added minimum (non-)working example, according to (@PaulSanders)'s request.

Edit 3: Live demos were missing "public:".

Edit 4: Live demo with solution from @Artyer.

Edit 5: Problem solved!

Comment: Do you know what concepts are, and how to use them?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I forgot to mention, I am bound to C++17. Shall I tag so?

Comment: @PaulSanders: I was hoping no one would complain. :-)
Please, tell me how do I use one of those online services where I can post (and test) my code.

Comment: C++20 works with concepts. The type of meta programming you are trying, is a relic. If you can't upgrade to C++20, use `static_assert` inside the constructor definition instead of `enable_if` on arguments. You can settle to **SFINAE** too; put your enable_if thingy as the last argument with a `bool` type and give it a default; But that won't work with varidic functions.

Comment: You can also provide a creator function and enforce the `enable_if` on return type.

Comment: @AndréCaldas I like this one: https://wandbox.org/

Comment: @PaulSanders: I have posted two (non-)working minimal examples.

Comment: Before I do anything else, did you try the answer posted here?

Comment: @PaulSanders: Yes, I did. It works. Your "push" for me to post the code also helped a lot. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo: `std::conjunction_v<std::is_constructible_v<X, Y>...>` should be either `std::conjunction_v<std::is_constructible<X, Y>...>` or `(std::is_constructible_v<X, Y> && ...)`.

Your first try doesn't work because `enable_if_t<condition, Type&&>` is a non-deduced context: The compiler can't guess what `enable_if_t<...>` is going to be (even if the programmer knows it's going to be `Type&&`).

Your second try doesn't work because a parameter pack that isn't the last argument is also a non-deduced context.

Instead of `enable_if_t<condition, bool> dummy = true` being the last function argument, make it the last template argument:

```cpp
    template<typename... NameOrTag, std::enable_if_t<
            std::conjunction_v
            <
                std::is_constructible<NameAndTag, NameOrTag>...
            >
            , bool> dummy = true>
    PathToObject(NameOrTag&&... obj_path);
```

This pattern is usually written as `std::enable_if_t<(condition)>* = nullptr`, being `void* = nullptr` if the condition is true, or an error otherwise.

Comment: I had tried that too... but since it was not working, I assumed there could be no enable_if after a template pack. I will try...

Comment: It works nice:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/Me3XHlrtZ58ye7Hl

Comment: Here is my code... with thanks. :-)
https://github.com/andre-caldas/FreeCAD/blob/0af3ad0d8a9681a1b3931166791b8a93094f4746/src/Base/Accessor/ReferenceToObject.h#L46